# Is Selenium Prohibited On Some Forms?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying for hours to make selenium find a certain field during the checkout on a website. All I need for that page is for Selenium to click and send the CVV numbers, but I have attempted every method and it still failed. This makes me wonder if Nike, in this example, banned automation during checkout.

The HTML is:

```
<input type="tel" id="cvNumber" tabindex="0" data-shortname="cvv" maxlength="4" placeholder="XXX" class="mod-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off
    value=" "="">
```

and I have tried finding it several different ways like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cvNumber']")
driver.find_element_by_id("cvNumber")
```

and many others. Please let me know if you have a fix or idea. Thanks